# Iteration and Subtraction of columns for graphs

Tags: graph, iterator

a question if I may.  I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.  I am using 3 csv files from https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases to produce graphs to track the covid 19 epidemic.  These are purely for my use to learn Python and Data Visualisation.  I have changed the dates in row one to be Day1, Day2 ect, dropped the Province/State, Lat, Long columns and set the Country/Region column as the index.  Each dataset now has 107 columns and 267 rows.  The three datasets are cases, deaths and recover.  Things are going ok but I have a slight problem and need some advice.  The graphs are updated with a new column each day and this causes me some problems when I try write code to show the daily increase in numbers from today over yesterday.  Currently I have to manually update my code each day to compensate for the extra columns in the 3 csv files as my code reads like:-

```
 daily_increase_C = [(0,
    (cases["Day1"].sum()- (0)),
    (cases["Day2"].sum()-cases["Day1"].sum()),
    (cases["Day3"].sum()-cases["Day2"].sum()),
    (cases["Day4"].sum()-cases["Day3"].sum()),
    (cases["Day5"].sum()-cases["Day4"].sum()),
    ---------------------------------------------
    (cases["Day102"].sum()-cases["Day101"].sum()),
    (cases["Day103"].sum()-cases["Day102"].sum()),
    (cases["Day104"].sum()-cases["Day104"].sum()),
    (cases["Day106"].sum()-cases["Day105"].sum()))]
```

So the last line has to be copied, pasted and then updated each day.  There has to be a better way of achieving this but new to coding as I am, I cannot seem to get my head around it and figure it out.
Any advice, pointers, help on how to look at and approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I hope I have explained this clearly enough for you, if not my apologies and please post your questions needing clarification.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Guys, I think I've cracked the problem now by not trying to subtract each column from the next but by finding the difference between the two columns.

Comment: UK_C = pd.DataFrame(cases[cases.index=="United Kingdom"])
    datavalues = UK_C
    dataFrameObject = pd.DataFrame(datavalues, columns = cases.columns)
    difference_C = dataFrameObject.diff(axis=1, periods=1).sum(axis=0)
    print("Difference between columns(Period=1):");
    print(difference_C)